# Uploading CSV using Sqlite3 Console - Different treatment of commas within quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, sqlite

I am currently experiencing problems associated with reading in CSV files to a sqlite3 database in a rails application.  I have around 20 CSV files each with 20k lines of data in them which i need to read into a database on a regular basis.

Having experimented with a few different approaches, I have opted for using `sqlite3 console` as this enables me to quickly upload the data (in seconds as opposed to hours going through Rails using the code I was using previously).  I tested this approach locally where I am running `sqlite 3.7.15.2` and successfully read in the data to my table `allitems` using the following commands:

```
  sqlite3 development.sqlite3
  .separator ','
  .import '../newdata.csv' allitems
```

Encouraged by my success, I proceeded to attempt to recreate this process on a live test site.  However, in this case I get a number of errors indicating that the number of columns in `newdata.csv` doesn't always match the number of columns in `allitems`.  I inspected the data in Excel and found all data to be in the correct number of columns required.  On further investigation, I discovered that it was commas within text strings which were causing the issues and found some information online (http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)suggesting `sqlite3` will always split on commas, regardless of whether they're inside quotes.

My first solution was to attempt to use a new separator which would never appear within the text strings (`,|,`), although this did succeed it also caused different problems as now many text fields when displayed on the webpage contain `"` at the start and end which has various knock on effects.  I created an additional work around for this, converting my separator to `","` and inserting `"` before and after fields which were not strings, but accounting for exceptions in the data is turning into a never ending fiddle.

Having lost patience with the above approach, I was looking for some advice as to how I could get around this problem?  In particular, I am puzzled as to why i do not have any problems when I run the code locally, but face all these issues on the server.  The server is currently running `sqlite 3.7.3` but I don't know if this is the cause of the issue, or how I could update the version remotely if it was...

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing CSV files robustly is complex; there are still somewhat frequent bugfixes for `sqlite3`'s import function.

Apparently, there was a necessary bugfix between versions 3.7.3 and 3.7.15.

The `sqlite3` tool does not really have any dependencies.
[Download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) or compile your own copy, rename it to whatever you like, and use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and it coincides with what i seem to be discovering.  Is there a way I can update this on a server - I guess I am wondering whether it can be done in a similar way to installing gems, or does this need to be done physically on the server machine?

Comment: Just copy the executable file to the server.